# Odoo 15 Qweb Foreach in Email Template

Tags: python, xml, templates, odoo, odoo-15

I'm lopping through a list of records when a function gets executed, the list is stored in a variable and then converted into a dictionary and finally send it to the email template and hopefully it generates table with a `t-foreach` so it can construct each line. but I'm getting stuck in the last part

```
def sh_mass_approved_timesheet(self):
    timesheet_details = []
    for timesheet in self:
        timesheet.sh_approved_by = self.env.user.id
        timesheet.sh_approved_date = fields.Datetime.now()
        timesheet.state = 'approved'

        timesheet_details.append({
                'date': timesheet.date,
                'description': timesheet.name,
                'project': timesheet.timecodes_id.name,
                'duration': timesheet.unit_amount,
            })

        # Pass as template context
        email_body = {
            'timesheet_details': timesheet_details,
        }
        # Send one email compiling the approved timesheets
        template = self.env.ref('sh_timesheet_approval.sh_approve_timesheet_template', raise_if_not_found=False)
        if template:
            template.sudo().send_mail(self.ids[0], force_send=True, email_body=email_body)
```

This is the template XML

```
<table border="1" style="font-family: arial, sans-serif; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;">
                        <tr>
                            <th style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px;"><b>Date</b></th>
                            <th style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px;"><b>Description</b></th>
                            <th style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px;"><b>Project</b></th>
                            <th style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px;"><b>Duration</b></th>
                        </tr>
                        <t t-foreach="timesheet_details" t-as="line">
                            <tr>
                                <td><t t-esc="line.date"/></td>
                                <td><t t-esc="line.description"/></td>
                                <td><t t-esc="line.project"/></td>
                                <td><t t-esc="line.duration"/></td>
                            </tr>
                        </t>
                    </table>
```

When I am running the application I get this error:
ValueError: <class 'ValueError'>: "Invalid field 'timesheet_details' on model 'mail.mail'" while evaluating
'records.sh_mass_approved_timesheet()'

Which It makes reference that the template is not accessing the list, for the record the logs for the variables 'timesheet_details' and 'email_body' are returning the correct data so passing the data to the template is the problem. Thank you

I did try another way to sending the data passing the dictionary but even though it does not get an error the email itself but shows the table empty.

```
template.sudo().with_context(email_body).send_mail(self.ids[0], force_send=True)
```

Comment: I don’t see that your code have any connection with your xml template? Where do you insert the values to the xml?

Comment: Certainly!. The template that I posted is part of the full template but the name of the template is declared in this part in python: ```template = self.env.ref('sh_timesheet_approval.sh_approve_timesheet_template'```.  after this we use the send_mail() to pass the context to the template.

Comment: How about using t-foreach="email_body['timesheet_details']" ?

Answer (score 0):

The mail model ***'mail.mail'***, i assume, is odoo default model for **mail app**.

You only show part of xml file, not all so i have no way to know what other model you use for the template, but assuming you only use **mail** model, what you should do is making new model inheriting odoo default model of **mail app**, and adding ***timesheet_details*** as *one2many field*, *calculated field* or other method you think seems fit.

In short, odoo wont recognize your ***timesheet_detail*** unless you declare it as a ***field*** in ***mail model***.